# Why is there a gap between the sphere (active rigid body) and the box below it (passive)?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I've an issue regarding my first rigid body simulation. I want this sphere to fall down on the second cube and then fall down to floor. But it's not falling down the cube properly, you see, it has a gap.

I've set every single objects margin to 0 but there is still the same issue. Every cube and sphere is set to *Mesh* and *Deform* source as default.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me a couple of times. The first thing I would check is the scale. If your objects are too big or too small, the simulation gets a bit wonky. Scale your model so your objects are around the size of the default cube.

Also, APPLY YOUR SCALE. This can be done by going to Objects -> Apply -> Scale. I've found that this can make the simulation more accurate. If you are still having problems, try turning up the masses of your objects in the Rigid Body properties. For some reason, heavier objects have more accurate collisions.

If you are still having issues, try turning up your Substeps and Solver Iterations in Scene Properties -> Rigid Body World.

I hope one of these tips can help you. Good luck with your project!